# Athena Create External Table ParseException

Tags: amazon-web-services, hiveql, ddl, amazon-athena

Hi I am trying to run the following command in Athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE transport_evaluator_prod(
    messageId STRING,
    type STRING,
    causationId STRING,
    correlationId STRING,
    traceparent STRING,
    `data` struct < 
    evaluationOccurred: STRING,
    eta struct < distance: INT,
    timeToDestination: INT,
    eta: STRING,
    destination struct < latitude: DOUBLE,
    longitude: DOUBLE,
    altitude: DOUBLE >,
    destinationEventId: STRING,
    origin struct < latitude: DOUBLE,
    longitude: DOUBLE,
    altitude: DOUBLE >, originEventId: STRING,
    plannedArrival: STRING,
    locationActionReference: STRING,
    resourceUrn: STRING,
    eventProvider: STRING,
    occured: STRING,
    position struct < latitude: DOUBLE,
    longitude: DOUBLE,
    altitude: DOUBLE >, 
    equipmentNumber: STRING,
    received: STRING > >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'serialization.format' = '1',
    'ignore.malformed.json' = 'true'
)
LOCATION 'changed-for-security'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data' = 'false')
```

Unfortunately when I try to run this I get the following error :
FAILED: ParseException line 1:189 missing : at 'struct' near '' line 1:262 missing : at 'struct' near '' line 1:363 missing : at 'struct' near '' line 1:579 missing : at 'struct' near ''

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reading [Create Tables in Amazon Athena from Nested JSON and Mappings Using JSONSerDe | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-tables-in-amazon-athena-from-nested-json-and-mappings-using-jsonserde/), I notice that any fields *inside* a `STRUCT` should be referenced as `field_name:type`.

This also applies to `struct`.

Therefore, this type of line (which is inside a `struct`):

```
destination struct < latitude: DOUBLE,
```

should be:

```
destination:struct < latitude: DOUBLE,
```

Thus, this seems to work:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE transport_evaluator_prod(
    messageId STRING,
    type STRING,
    causationId STRING,
    correlationId STRING,
    traceparent STRING,
    `data` struct < 
        evaluationOccurred: STRING,
        eta:struct < distance: INT,
            timeToDestination: INT,
            eta: STRING,
            destination:struct < latitude: DOUBLE,
                longitude: DOUBLE,
                altitude: DOUBLE >,
            destinationEventId: STRING,
            origin:struct < latitude: DOUBLE,
                longitude: DOUBLE,
                altitude: DOUBLE >,
            originEventId: STRING,
            plannedArrival: STRING,
            locationActionReference: STRING,
            resourceUrn: STRING,
            eventProvider: STRING,
            occured: STRING,
            position:struct < latitude: DOUBLE,
                longitude: DOUBLE,
                altitude: DOUBLE >, 
            equipmentNumber: STRING,
            received: STRING > >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'serialization.format' = '1',
    'ignore.malformed.json' = 'true'
)
LOCATION 'changed-for-security'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data' = 'false')
```